# Trace of gravitational Weyl spinor

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, spinors, trace

If two of the indices of the gravitational Weyl spinor $\Psi^{ABCD}$ is contracted, does it vanish?  I mean does it follow from the traceless nature of the Weyl tensor that $\Psi^{A}_{~~BAD}=0$?

Comment: It vanishes by definition.

Comment: Sorry for being late, but can you please elaborate why should the object $\Psi^A_{~BAD}$ vanish? I can understand that if we contract all the indices, it does vanish, but if one or some of the indices are traced, how can one say that this vanish?

Comment: The trace is taken with $\epsilon_{AB}$ and $\Psi_{ABCD}$ is totally symmetric.

Comment: My bad. Thanks.